# how to remove [object object] based on value not based on key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to **remove** all `[object object]` from my `json` not based on key but based on value i,e (`[object object]`).

**here is my json**

```js
var allProductSpecification = {
            "Vinyl_Backlite": [{
              "Price": "280",
              "Quantity": "1",
              "Amount": "280"
            }],
            "Steel": [{
              "Price": "18",
              "Quantity": "1",
              "Amount": "18"
            }],
            "0": "[object Object]",
            "1": "[object Object]"
          }
   
   allProductSpecification = JSON.parse(allProductSpecification);
   
   delete  allProductSpecification[0];
   
    delete  allProductSpecification[1];
   
   console.log(allProductSpecification);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

here is how  i have removed a [object object] from key:0

```
delete  allProductSpecification[0];
```

**Question:** how can i do it for any number of `[object object]` dynamically

Comment: Do you have control of the code which creates this object? It would make far more sense to fix the problem there, at the source

Comment: i don't control that code it generated by some plugin complex code, that i don't understand

Comment: What is `[object object]` supposed to be? Looks like some `console.log` in a output less capable dev tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with the condition to add only those key whose value is not `[object Object]`.

```js
var allProductSpecification = { "Vinyl_Backlite": [{ "Price": "280", "Quantity": "1", "Amount": "280" }], "Steel": [{ "Price": "18", "Quantity": "1", "Amount": "18" }], "0": "[object Object]", "1": "[object Object]" },
    result = Object.keys(allProductSpecification).reduce((r,k) => {
      if(allProductSpecification[k] !== '[object Object]')
        r[k] = allProductSpecification[k];
      return r;
    },{});
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i have asked this question so many times no one was able to give answer, but you are there thank you very much , i had only one upvote !!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

If you do have a JSON string (not javascript object literal as you have posted as example). Then you could use custom reviver with `JSON.parse`

```js
const json = `{
            "Vinyl_Backlite": [{
              "Price": "280",
              "Quantity": "1",
              "Amount": "280"
            }],
            "Steel": [{
              "Price": "18",
              "Quantity": "1",
              "Amount": "18"
            }],
            "0": "[object Object]",
            "1": "[object Object]"
          }`;
          
const obj = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => (value === {}.toString() ? undefined : value))

console.log(obj)
```